# What are components and tags in the manifest? [Android]

Tags: android, tags, components, android-manifest, manifest

I'm trying to understand what Is meant by components and that they can have tags for each component in the manifest. Does that mean like buttons or edit text are the components and android:width, android:height, android:hint..etc are the tags?

Answer (score 3):

No. Components are activities, services, content providers, and broadcast receivers. Those will have `<activity>`, `<service>`, `<provider>`, and `<receiver>` tags in the manifest, for those that are in your app that you are using (exception: some receivers can be registered in other ways).

Answer (score 1):

This is the manifest structure

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<manifest>

    <uses-permission />
    <permission />
    <permission-tree />
    <permission-group />
    <instrumentation />
    <uses-sdk />
    <uses-configuration />  
    <uses-feature />  
    <supports-screens />  
    <compatible-screens />  
    <supports-gl-texture />  

    <application>

        <activity>
            <intent-filter>
                <action />
                <category />
                <data />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data />
        </activity>

        <activity-alias>
            <intent-filter> . . . </intent-filter>
            <meta-data />
        </activity-alias>

        <service>
            <intent-filter> . . . </intent-filter>
            <meta-data/>
        </service>

        <receiver>
            <intent-filter> . . . </intent-filter>
            <meta-data />
        </receiver>

        <provider>
            <grant-uri-permission />
            <meta-data />
            <path-permission />
        </provider>

        <uses-library />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

You dont have to use all the elements, components or tags, depends about the application and features, you have a  great documentation about the [MANIFEST](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html?hl=en)